# Sed script file that makes new lines

Tags: sed

This should be easy, but I clearly don't understand how sed -f  works.

I start with a txt file, bar.txt:

```
set_expand [get_it -marker \*spam*]
```

I want the output to be:

```
{Line1:# EXPAND ####\n############\n#{print set_expand [get_it -marker \*spam*]\n###
Line2:set_expand [foo\*spam*]"}
```

As I said, I thought this would be easy because running consecutive functions, it's "just":

```
sed -e 's/\(^set_expand[^\n]*$\)/{Line1:# EXPAND ####\\n############\\n#{print \1\\n###\nLine2:\1"}/g' bar.txt >tmp.txt
sed -e '/^[{]/\!{s/get_it -marker[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)$/foo\1/g}' tmp.txt
```

to produce the desired output:

```
{Line1:# EXPAND ####\n############\n#{print set_expand [get_it -marker *spam*]\n###
Line2:set_expand [foo*spam*]"}
```

But, when I put it into a script for sed -f, the second line is skipped.
Here's my .sed file, create_awk.sed

```
s/\(^set_expand[^\n]*$\)/{Line1:# EXPAND ####\\n############\\n#{print \1\\n###\nLine2:\1"}/g
/^[{]/!{s/get_it -marker[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)$/foo\1/g}
```

The output loses the replacement on Line2:

```
sed -f create_awk.sed bar.txt
{Line1:# EXPAND ####\n############\n#{print set_expand [get_it -marker *spam*]\n###
Line2:set_expand [get_it -marker *spam*]"}
```

I think the problem is that the first line of the .sed file is creating an additional line that never gets into the pattern buffer for the second buffer to operate on.

Comment: In your `.sed` file you use '!' where you used '\!' in the first file. Typo?

Comment: Good eye, but no. The ! has to be escaped in the shell  (or else it is interpreted as the command history) but cannot be escaped in the .sed script.

Comment: Nevertheless I cannot reproduce your problem in a simplified script: `s/B/\n&\n/ ; s/B/2/` -> `echo ABC | sed -f simple.sed` -> `A\n2\nC`. So it is not a problem of `sed` not aplying each script line to all input.

Comment: I don't necessarily understand your notation, but here's a simpler version of the problem:
input file is the same.
sed file - 
`s/\(^set_expand[^\n]*$\)/{Line1\n#Line2"}/g
/^[{]/!{s/Line2/foo/g}`
Result:
`{Line1
#Line2"}
`
Calling them separately as 
`sed -e 's/\(^set_expand[^\n]*$\)/{Line1\n#Line2"}/g' bar.txt >tmp.txt`
`sed -e '/^[{]/\!{s/Line2/foo/g}' tmp.txt`
produces the expected result:
`{Line1
#foo"}`

Comment: Same example as above, but removing the address `/^[{]/! does work. Using the address /[#]/ also fails, though. So, it has something to do with the address, not just the inversion.

Comment: Using your scripts (finally figured out what you were doing) I found something interesting: sed = `s/A/A\nB\n/ ; s/B/2/` --> same command yields: `A\n2\nBC` I expected `A\n2\n2C`

Comment: The last would be solved using this replacement command: `s/B/2/g`  - note that without the `g`, `sed` will only execute the command **on the first finding in a line**. Also you should expect `A\n2BC` as output, don't you?

Comment: @Fiximan, you are right about the s/B/2/g doing the substitution on the second line. Thank you. I now see the final result I expected: `A\n2\n2C`. I had the /g in the original script, though, so this isn't the final solution. I am stumped now because your simplified process of `echo abc | sed -f simple.sed` is doing exactly what I expect but my real script is still acting up. I explored if the {s or the #s were causing the problem, but they worked well in the `echo abc` method. Any suggestions for next steps?